# Godot: Animation Tree, Animations aren't available

Tags: animation, godot4

I am using the Godot 4 Animation Tree State Machine, and there a Blend Space 2D, but if I want to add an animation, the prepared ones from my animation player aren't shown.

I tried animating my character for a simple 2D game, but it is my first time using the Godot Engine.
When I tried adding an animation to my Animation Tree State Machine, they are not displayed.

[Here my animations aren't shown, even though they should](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNd0k.png)

[Here are my animations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qnwt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at you tree node, I see that there is a warning on your animation tree node. I guess you did not set the anim player property to your animation player.

So your animations will not be shown in the animation tree, because it does not know your player.

[image: Simply click this]

Simply click this button and select your animation player.